# Stuck on Initial SQL Server Configuration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008

I'm working with a fresh installation of Server 2008 R2.  I'm new to all things administration, so this could be a simple issue.

I'm installing SQL Server 2008 R2, and I've reached a point where it's asking me to create  Service Accounts.  I'm really just trying to do bare minimum here to get started with SharePoint.

I'm getting an error "The credentials you provided for the SQL Server Agent service are invalid.  To continue, provide a valid account and password."

I get this error for the Analysis Services service as well.

Can someone explain to me what this means and how I can proceed with the installation?

After some searching I saw that the issue might lie in the fact that I was signed in as a local Administrator, so I created another user in Users via Computer Management and the same issue is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL installation is not asking to create service accounts. It is asking which service accounts it should use to execute SQL Server. If you need to create accounts for this, you will need to do that through the usual user management tools, whether Active Directory or Local Users.

Depending on the purposes of this machine, you may be fine using one of the built in accounts, such as Network Service. Not a best practice, but maybe adequate for a short lived demo/dev machine.

More details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx).

Comment: Great, Thank you.  I installed AD and got it working.  Cheers!